# Audio player on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm trying to develop specialized audio player for windows mobile devices (Professional ones). And I've ran into the problem an once.

There no compressed audio APIs on WM or I was unable to found house in documentation. Yes there are WM6 Sound API but it cannot even pause playback or seek to specified position. There are allways Windows Media Player on WM device but I've not found it APIs documentation.

So the question is:
Is there simple way to play, pause, forward, rewind, getting playback position and getting audio file length on *compressed* audio of several popular formats? Any library? platform APIs? Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found quite a sufficient compressed audio playback library [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/). There are WM version of it. And I've found sample application on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/simple_mp3_player_for_ppc.aspx) to start with.

Answer (score 2):

This might be of no help at all, but the (very good) podcast player [BeyondPod](http://www.codeplex.com/beyondpod) has a built in player, based on Windows Media Player, and it's open source - so you could have a look at what API they are using.

Obviously if they've written their own custom player, you wont be able to just copy it if you're writing a commercial app. But you could use it for API documentation if they're just calling through to some Media Player API.