# How can I play .ogg, mp3, without Directsound libs in Windows CE 5.0 (Build 1400) in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've been facing  a road block in trying to incorporate .ogg and .mp3 files in a WinCE 5.0 (build 1400) environment. Many of the answers I've found require some part of the Directsound libraries which are no longer supported.

Is there any way to implement playing of .ogg and .mp3 files on WinCE 5.0 without using Directsound libraries?

Comment: Have you found any workable and free solution?

Answer (score 1):

For this situation I would recommend taking a look at [GSPlayer](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source_codes/gsplayer.cfm) or [TCPMP Player](http://www.hpcfactor.com/downloads/tcpmp/) (open source software, C++), you could use the code to create a dll. GSPlayer uses WaveOut internally, so no worries about DirectSound. However you will need to check the license and make sure you are not violating it. After creating such dll you could use it with p/invoke.
 
If you are the OEM of your target device, [another option that excludes .ogg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee492321%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx) would be to add [Windows Media Player Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940102.aspx) in your OS image, and use it from C# as an ActiveX control. There is more information on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544856/activex-hosting-using-the-concept-of-alex-feinman-doent-work-on-my-hp-ipaq-rx572), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/21dd84d8-6290-41b0-93fe-f26f121e9941)

Update:
In [answers to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233/audio-player-on-windows-mobile) it is recommended to use FMOD, although this is not free for commercial use as @mack369 pointed out in a comment.

Comment: FMOD isn't free for commercial use. Are you sure that there is no way to play ogg using the Windows Media Player ?

Comment: @mack369 Yes, I am sure of this. Take a look at the reference I added, and this reference is for Windows CE 6.0 R3, the original question was for Windows CE 5.0, which I assume supported even fewer formats.